# Did Wags mean that he and Axe had been to prison?

Tags: billions

In Billions S02E11 (Golden Frog Time), Axe says "Call it what you will, but we all know you've gotta shank someone to earn respect on the yard."

Taylor then asks "How many jailhouse movies did you two watch growing up?"

Wags says "We didn't have computers".

Does Wags' line mean that they learned such talk from actually being in prison?

Answer (score 4):

**No.** The line seems very literal to me: Wags and Axe did not own any computers when they were growing up. What he's suggesting is that movies were all they had to entertain themselves with, and therefore, they watched a *lot* of jailhouse movies.

Rather than answering the question directly, Wags is trying to justify the number of jailhouse movies he and Axe watched as kids.